# Changeset (Trigger) Deployment fails in Production even though it passed in Sandbox

Tags: apex, trigger, unit-test, code-coverage, change-set

I wrote a  trigger to update Target Account Checkbox on Lead Object if any of the existing queue checkbox fields is true in Sandbox. But when I try to deploy it in Production it fails stating 0% code coverage and some Test Failures.

I selected Run all Tests during Validation and the test failed due to a class which is already commissioned in the environment long back which I am unaware of.

Should I create a Test class for this trigger and select "Run specified class" or should I delete the old class to make this trigger functional?
Please help! Trigger and error screenshots are attached[image].

```
trigger TargetAccount on Lead (before insert, before update) {
    for (Lead ld : Trigger.new){
        if(ld.Dylan_s_Target_Queue__c  == true || ... ){
           ld.Target_Account__c = true; 
        } else {
           ld.Target_Account__c = false; 
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

All triggers must be covered by a testmethod (i.e. a testmethod that does actual DML on the `Lead` in your case)

If you don't deploy a testmethod that does insertion/update of `Lead` and no other testclass does DML on Lead, the error you got is expected